# How to show conditionals label and no-label?

Tags: c3.js

To show label is working, the problem is to show no-label. I am using

```
labels: {
        format: function (v, id) {
            return (String(id).substring(0,5)=='avg')? d3.format(".3")(v): null;
        }
},
```

but null (or `""` or *undefined*) not works, generates `0`  as label. See in a `bar` chat, the non-solicitaed zeros:

[image]

---

See https://output.jsbin.com/seriyih/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3.format is turning any undefineds and nulls into '0', so you just need a further conditional test for this and dodge the formatting step if so.

```
    format: (v, id)=> (  (String(id).substring(0,3)=='avg')? (v != undefined ? d3.format(".3")(v) : null): null)
```